# How can I ingnore some elements when reading XML using Jackson/FasterXML?

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I want to skip all nodes except first_name ,node100 and its children.
I have this XML (In reality I have many employee  and each employee tag has many nodes):

```
 <employees>
        <employee>
            <first_name>John</first_name>
            <last_name>Doe</last_name>
            <age>26</age>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <first_name>Peter</first_name>
            <last_name>Parker</last_name>
            <age>30</age>
        </employee>
    </employees>
```

I am able to read the using Jackson FasterXML.  I have created 2 POJOS to map above XML structure

```
  @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "employees") public final class Employees {
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "employee", useWrapping = false)
        private Employee[] employee;
//ommiteed getter and setters

public final class Employee {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    private String id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "age")
    private int age;
```

Now in production the xml have 1000s nodes inside  node

```
<employee>
                <first_name>John</first_name>
                <last_name>Doe</last_name>
                <age>26</age>
                <node1>  </node1>
                <node2>  </node2>

                ..

                <node100> 
                   <values> 
                  <value> val1 </value>
                  <value> val1 </value>
                  <value> val1 </value>
                  <value> val1 </value>
                  </node100> 

            </employee>


    <node100>  is also inside 4-5 nodes (which i have not shown above).
```

So my question is how can I just read  first_name , last_name,  and  tag .
What should be the structure of my POJO class ?

Code to convert XML to POJO

```
System.out.println( " hello");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
// Reads from XML and converts to POJO
Employees employees = objectMapper.readValue(
        StringUtils.toEncodedString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\91895\\Downloads\\File\\XmlFile.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        Employees.class);
System.out.println(employees);
```

Comment: *how can I just read first_name , last_name, and tag* - What you beam by *tag*?

Comment: By tag I mean node.

Comment: If you want to read also *node* elements, it means you want to read everything. But your words *just read* mean you wanted to skip some elements. What exactly want you to read and what to skip?

Comment: Yes you are right.I didn't frame the question correctly. I want to skip all nodes except first_name ,node100 and its children.So how can I create my POJO class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class define the elements that you want to read from XML. To ignore other elements configure ObjectMapper correspondingly:

```
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

Comment: thanks this is what I was looking for.Just one doubt the was I am reading the file is correct ?As I don't want to load the whole file at once in memory.It's a huge file.

Comment: To *I don't want to load the whole file at once in memory* - You can use different techniques for this. For instance, you can implement your own SAXParser or you can use streaming API (see example here). Then you have a control when to create further elements or not.

Comment: `objectMapper.readValue(
        StringUtils.toEncodedString(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\91895\\Downloads\\File\\XmlFile.xml")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
        Employees.class);`

So you are saying currently I am loading the whole file at once.And I should use stream api with Jackson?Your "you can use streaming API (see example here)" is not working.

Comment: No. Streaming API **instead** of Jackson. The file will be read till the end. But you will have a possibility to decide that for instance you only create 5 objects and you can just ignore any further occurrences of objects.

Comment: If you have a large file like 1TB and want to read only first 100K, then you can also implement your own InputStream that stops after reading 100K. Of course you have then to correctly react on corresponding exceptions.

Comment: ok stax will be more verbose and error prone.Thats why I prefer using JACKSON